# CoreData and a large initial data load

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm performing a large initial data load into coredata on iOS.  My app comes loaded with about 500 compressed JSON files (about 250MB inflated). I sequentially decompress and load each file into coredata.  I'm pretty sure I am closing all the streams. In the beginning I had a large connected graph using relationships.  I have since replaced all relationships with URIs; so, there is no explicit object graph.  My store type is SQLlite. I'm assuming an iPhone 6 at iOS 12+.

Data is loaded on a background queue and I can watch the progress on my iOS device. I do periodic context saves and resets at logical stopping points.

My problem is the initial data load consumes too much memory, about 600MB before it's terminated because of memory issues.  If I stop the loading about half way, memory consumption will peak at 300MB+ and then rapidly fall off to to 13MB. It doesn't look like a memory leak. Apart from the managed object context there are no objects that span the breadth of the load.

What this looks like to me is that CoreData is not flushing anything to storage because it's lower priority than my inserts. In other words, the backlog grows too fast.

If I add a delay using `asyncAfter` to the last half of the data load, it will start at the low water mark or about 13MB.

So here are the questions:

- does my diagnosis seem plausible?
- is there some magic method that will cause CoreData to flush its cache
- can I create a queue that is lower priority than whatever coredata is using to flush objects to storage?
- conversely, do I need to throttle my inserts?
- am I using coredata in a manner it wasn't designed for (i.e., ~250MB data base)?

Comment: Show how you import your data, otherwise that is kinda hard to tell. Are you using autoreleasepools for your different contexts? The amount of data should not be an issue. How are you loading your json files - using autoreleasepools there? Can you identify the allocations in instruments?

Comment: I am not using autoreleasepools.  In fact, I was barely aware of such a thing. After doing a little research, I inserted them at appropriate places and reset the context before leaving the autoreleasepool.  Memory now maxes out at about 100MB.  Going from C to C++ to Java to Python over a few decades does not quite prepare one for Swift memory management.  Thanks.  Your hint was enough to solve the problem.